# I have existing tables and want to make Autonumber the Primary key in one table and Foreign key in the other table. What is a good way?

Tags: ms-access

In Access, I have one table called courses and another table called lessons

the table courses

```
id  name    code
1   english LEN
2   german  LDE
3   math    SMA
```

the table lessons

```
id  name        coursename  class_id
1   shakespare  english     ?
2   hesse       german      ?
3   trigonometrymath        ?
4   algebra     math        ?
5   whitman     english     ?
```

Previously I used course name as a primary key in courses and a foreign key in classes. Now I want to use the autonumber field course_id instead. What is a good way to make this transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little messed up compared to the tables you are presenting.  What I understand is you have an autonumber field in `courses` named `id`.  You want to store that in `lessons` in a field called `course_id`.  If this is true then follow the following:

The easiest way would be to open the `lessons` table in design view. Add the `course_id` field to the table as a long integer and save.  Then execute the following query:

```
UPDATE lessons
INNER JOIN courses ON courses.name = lessons.coursename
SET lessons.course_id = courses.id
```

Then open the `lessons` table in design view again and delete the `coursename` field.